# DropZoneJS: Uploading file prints html in dropzone area

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

While uploading file in my Laravel app, I am getting following along with picture

[image]

Comment: does that happen with all pictures that u upload or just this one?

Comment: all pictures and text files.

Comment: that happens because file was unable to upload to your server. And it appends the error to the image. (actually not to the image, to the image message)

Comment: @naneri Ah! yes right now it just redirects to a valid URL but not an Upload URL. How to deal with it?

Comment: the image redirects or what? Actually nothing is supposed to redirect ;D

Comment: not rediecting anywhere

Comment: By default Dropzone uploads the images asyncronously not redirecting you anywhere. Do you want to redirect after you submit the form?

Comment: No I want it to be ajaxified, the uploading process only. Later I already have a form submit process separately to store other fields.

Comment: Ok, I don't get what happens. The dropzone sends the files via AJAX, and you also want them to be sent via AJAX. So whats the problem right now? :D

Comment: @naneri No I mean I don't need any redirection. You and me saying same thing. My point is how do script figure out file was not uploaded and prints this error? which code do I use to sort it out?

Comment: When you add a form with Dropzone (or initialize it via JS), you setup a URL for the action. Dropzone uses it a a destination to send files via AJAX. If sending was not successfull, if will return the response from your server and append it as an error message. Because you are using laravel it shows that huge error message ;D

Comment: you should add your code of how you initialize your dropzone, and also the route that is responsible for processing the request, so that we could help you.